# Implementing "More" button in tableView without reloading the whole tableView again

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an iOS application in which i have a UITableView containing list of people coming from web-service and i have a more button on bottom. When user clicks on more it calls a service which provides some new people for the list. Now i want to add this list with the previous tableView list without reloading the whole tableView. how do i achieve this.

[image]
Any help would be really appreciable. I can provide my code of more button where i'm calling the service to get the data from service.

Comment: **WITHOUT RELOADING THE TABLEVIEW IT IS NOT POSSIBLE** You can only reload the new cell.

Comment: Instead of telling us what you do not want - why not telling us why you are so keen on preventing a reload on the table?

Comment: As I know without reloading the tableview we can't show the new names in the tableview.

Comment: He said without reloading the whole table view.

Comment: i don't want to reload whole table coz m calling a separate API for images of people.. so it will become too slow if i have to load 100-500 people. that's the reason i'm implementing more button.

Answer (score 3):

UITableview provides several APIs for manipulating the content. You should use the

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

method. The way how they should be applied is described in the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW19).

Practically, when the button is clicked, you start the network request for the list of names and when that finishes, you add the rows to the table with the above API.

Note: as long as you do only this modification to the table view, you don't have to use the `beginUpdates`, `endUpdates` methods. If there are multilple changes carried out at once (deletion, addition, reordering) then the `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [UITableView's  - beginUpdates;](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW15) and [- endUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW14) method.

In between calling these you'd have to insert the rows into the table view. If you are using [UITableView's - insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW38) method you can even skip the `begin-` and `endUpdates`.

Make sure to insert your new objects to your data source object before calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don;t want to reload the table then, at least, you have to call

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:
```

except that you can't show the newly added data in your table view.

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience , `It is not possible` to add/display new names to table view without reloading it.

**But you can achieve your task as follows ;**

You can set `arraCount(one varaible) for namesArray count`. After calling webservice, you can `increment arrayCount varaiable and reload the table view` , which will display new added names in the table.

Hope this will help.