# Fixed number of cells in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to fixed number of cells to be shown. If user wants to see more records, he will scroll down to see them.

I also want to add a button at the bottom of the table view to move to other view.

Comment: Please at least show us what you have tried?

Comment: Do you want to do something like this. if Yes lemme know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893837/implementing-more-button-in-tableview-without-reloading-the-whole-tableview-ag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`UITableView`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you are looking for.

> An instance of UITableView (or simply, a table view) is a means for
>   displaying and editing hierarchical lists of information. A table view
>   displays a list of items in a single column.

There are many resources on the Internet that can help you. Example tutorials:

[iOS UITableView Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/)

[Create a Simple Table View App](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

Comment: not completely satisfied .

Answer (score 0):

To add add button to the bottom of UITableView, just create a UIView(say 320 x 50) and add a UIButton on it. Create IBOutlet of this View. Set this view as footerView of your tableView,

```
self._table.tableFooterView = yourView;
```